# How to merge subarrays by a single key value and count the duplicates?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, duplicates, counting

I'm new to stackoverflow and I need some help.

I'm trying to remove the duplicates from a multi-dimension array in PHP such as:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 01/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 01/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 1 )
    [2] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 03/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 03/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 1 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 03/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 1 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 03/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 1 )
)
```

and create an array that removes the duplicates and adds to `Quan` the number of duplicates it as found like this (filtered by data) :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 01/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 2 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Plat] => hello [Data] => 03/01/2015 [Term] => PHP [Quan] => 4 ) 
)
```

My code is the folowing: (`$top` is the array)

```
foreach($top as $value){
    if(!empty($temp_top)){
        for($i =0;$i<sizeof($temp_top);$i++){
            if($value['Data'] == $temp_top[$i]['Data'] ){
                $temp_top[$i]['Quan'] +=1;
            }else{
                $temp_top[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $temp_top[] = $value;
    }
}
```

I've tried some answers that I found here on stack such as:

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $top)));
```

but I can't add how many there are to `Quan`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: Jonathan Bender, i don't think its a duplicate but thanks.. i've seen that and used the code that was explained there but I can't update the [Quan] :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself with the help of other posts.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
$temp_top = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $top)));
    $numvezesfound=0;

    foreach($temp_top as $key => $value){
            for($i =0;$i<sizeof($top);$i++){
                if($value['Data'] == $top[$i]['Data'] ){
                    $numvezesfound +=1;
                }
            }
            $temp_top[$key]['Quan'] = $numvezesfound;
            $numvezesfound = 0;
        }       
    $top = $temp_top;
```

if someone can help me make this code more beautifull I would be in your debt :)

thanks everyone tho!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement temporary keys so that as you iterate your array, you can determine if you are handling the first occurrence of `Data` or not.  If not, you merely add the current `Quan` value to the first occurrence's `Quan` value.

When finished looping, you remove the temporary keys (reindex) by calling `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/MeAVA))

```
$array = [
    ["Plat" => "hello", "Data" => "01/01/2015", "Term" => "PHP", "Quan" => "1"],
    ["Plat" => "hello", "Data" => "01/01/2015", "Term" => "PHP", "Quan" => "1"],
    ["Plat" => "hello", "Data" => "03/01/2015", "Term" => "PHP", "Quan" => "1"],
    ["Plat" => "hello", "Data" => "03/01/2015", "Term" => "PHP", "Quan" => "1"],
    ["Plat" => "hello", "Data" => "03/01/2015", "Term" => "PHP", "Quan" => "1"],
    ["Plat" => "hello", "Data" => "03/01/2015", "Term" => "PHP", "Quan" => "1"],
];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['Data']])) {
        $result[$row['Data']] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$row['Data']]['Quan'] += $row['Quan'];
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Plat' => 'hello',
    'Data' => '01/01/2015',
    'Term' => 'PHP',
    'Quan' => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Plat' => 'hello',
    'Data' => '03/01/2015',
    'Term' => 'PHP',
    'Quan' => 4,
  ),
)
```

*Note if you want to ignore the `Quan` value and just add `1` each time, you can use:

```
if (!isset($result[$row['Data']])) {
    $result[$row['Data']]['Quan'] = 1;
} else {
    ++$result[$row['Data']]['Quan'];
}
```

Your question is ambiguous on this logic because of the `Quan` column data.