# Merge array by key and sum another key

Tags: php, arrays, sum, key

I have this array and I need merge by key "name", also sum key "price", more in code example. Keys are static.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sapiente quo incidunt nostrum dolore
            [price] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Global Donation
            [price] => 10
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Global Donation
            [price] => 10
        )

)
```

Desired result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sapiente quo incidunt nostrum dolore
            [price] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Global Donation
            [price] => 20
        )
)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Is this coming from a mysql server or has it some other source? Knowing this could give you more accurate answers.

Comment: Just asked 20 minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32619813/3933332 and was also asked in another question today ...

Comment: @Rizier123 to be fair, he is not just de-duping an array but also asking how to sum a value at the same time. And @OP, is this from a query? Because this could likely be done right in the query by grouping on the name and getting `sum(price)` as the column. Aside from that, have you tried to solve this yourself? Or are you just expecting someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found it

```
    $items = array();
    foreach($prepare as $k=>$v) {
        if(!isset($items[$v['name']])) {
            $items[$v['name']] = $v;
        } else {
            $items[$v['name']]['price'] += $v['price'];
        }
    }
```